# improving performance in pose mode

Tags: pose-mode

I have a 1M poly character, and in pose mode any manipulation will freeze Blender for a few seconds. Disabling the armature modifier won't fix it, only deleting the mesh. Is there a way to increase performance for hig poly rigs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many strategies to animate high poly meshes.

The "professional" way is to retopologize the character, baking all small details into a normal map, so to be able to animate and export a low or mid poly mesh.

Another way is to create a low poly proxy, to be used for programming the animation, and then use the high poly version only for render.

In the render properties panel you can enable the "simplify" option, to allow only a low or null level of subsurf (and let it operate only during render).

You can add a decimate modifier to the mesh to reduce the amount of vertices, and disable it for render.

You can split the mesh into pieces and turn them off when you don't need to look at them.

Comment: Thanks, in the end I duplicated the mesh and decimated the copy.